# Is there a way to run an async function only when a file is updated instead of html onload=

Tags: javascript, html, json, asynchronous

I am using this code to input a .json file that gets updated every minute into a function that changes the image according to the .json data. The problem is that I summon the function with the onload= html property and it runs the async function continuously which uses a lot of performance.

'''

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8"/>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="profile.json"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            
            async function request() {
                
                const image = document.getElementById("RankImg");                                                                   ///set img var
                const text = document.getElementById("ValoRank")

                    fetch("profile.json")
                        .then(response => response.json())
                        .then(data => {
                            console.log(data.response)
                            var requestrank = data.response.substring(0, 4)
                            console.log(requestrank)
                            switch (requestrank) {                                                                                           ///switch start
                                case "Iron":
                                    image.src = 'Images/Iron.png' ;
                                    text.innerHTML = data.response ;
                                    break;
                                case "Bron":
                                    image.src = 'Images/Bronze.png' ;
                                    text.innerHTML = data.response ;
                                    break;
                                case "Silv":
                                    image.src = 'Images/Silver.png' ;
                                    text.innerHTML = data.response ;
                                    break;
                                case "Gold":
                                    image.src = 'Images/Gold.png' ;
                                    text.innerHTML = data.response ;
                                    break;
                                case "Plat":
                                    image.src = 'Images/Platinum.png' ;
                                    text.innerHTML = data.response ;
                                    break;
                                case "Diam":
                                    image.src = 'Images/Diamond.png' ;
                                    text.innerHTML = data.response ;
                                    break;
                                case "Immo":
                                    image.src = 'Images/Immortal.png' ;
                                    text.innerHTML = data.response ;
                                    break;
                                case "Radi":
                                    image.src = 'Images/Radiant.png' ;
                                    text.innerHTML = data.response ;
                                    break;
                                default:
                                    image.src = 'Images/Base.png' ;
                            }
                        })               
            }                                                                                                       ///Twitch.tv/QuentinCly

        </script>                                           
    </head>
    <body>

        <img src="Images/Base.png" alt="Valorant Rank" id="RankImg" onload="request().catch(error => {
            console.error(error);
        })">

    <h1><span id="ValoRank">Valorant Rank </span></h1>

    </body>
</html>
```

'''
Instead of summoning the request() function via onload, iI would like to summon it once the profile.json is updated.

Comment: The UI has no clue if a file is updated. Only way to know is to check it. Or maybe I am not sure what you are really asking.

Comment: I basically want to summon the function in a more optimised way than onload because it repeats the function indefinitely

Comment: So just call the script on page load or document ready or just place the script after the image.

Comment: like put the script after the html image ? and just keep it onload ? wont it just keep doing the same thing

Comment: no onload, just call `request()`

Answer (score 1):

Problem you have is every time you load a new image src, it fires a new onload event. So if you do not want that to happen you can either remove the inline event listener

```js
const image = document.querySelector("img");

function request() {
  console.log('loaded');
  image.onload = null;
  image.src="http://placekitten.com/200/400";
}
```

```html
<img onload="request()" src="http://placekitten.com/200/300" />
```

Or bind the event with window onload

```
window.addEventListener("load", request);
```

Or call the script after the image is on the page

```
<img />
<script>request();</script>
```